# Excel lookup value in all rows, not just 1st match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the following table with columns ID and X1, and I want to obtain X2.
[image: pic]

If one row is YES in the X1 column, then in X2 column all rows with that same ID should be YES. Otherwise it should be NO.
For example, ID=106629-1 (yellow) has 2 rows with NO but 1 with YES, then all three should be YES in X2 column. The other 2 IDs (orange and blue) have all rows with NO, then X2 should be NO as well.

I've tried `VLOOKUP`, but it only considers the 1st match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS to see if any are marked `YES`

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"YES"),"YES","NO")
```

[image]